# How to add a href functionality to sidebar menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar menu [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3st12rkgAfoMMakJTiFw?p=preview) which built with [AdminLte](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) framework.
I want to be able to click on the "parent" links and navigate to their content, 
for example - when clicking the "Home" button - i want to navigate to home.html  and also open the sub menu. I've tried a lot of possible solutions found here - but i didn't manage to make it work.

First i've tried to load to content by doing something like that :

```
 `
  $('.treeview a').on('click',function(){ // the class of the Li

   var current_url = $(this).attr('href'); 

   $( ".content" ).load(current_url+ ' .div-cont'); 
}
);`
```

The classes above appears in 
        the dev project - i didn't manage to recreate the whole project here.
       Problem with this solution is that the url doesn;t change - and the js file aren't loaded....

Thanks
Roy.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line from `script.js`:

```
e.is(".treeview-menu") && a.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Oh, I understood your problem wrong. Check this library to manage browser history: https://github.com/falsandtru/pjax-api